# Nginx 500 Error on POST to database, But It Actually Posts

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django app running on a droplet right now on DigitalOcean. It is running Nginx, gunicorn, MySQL.

When I POST a form, it gets added to the database, but I get a 500 server error. I just go back to my homepage and test what I just did, and it's fine. Why am I getting the 500 error?

I also get this error when I go to my admin page and try to view the actual item in my database.

**UPDATE**

So I changed over to `MySQL`, which I had originally built my app using, and everything seems to be working fine. Nothing in the logs led me to believe it was the database that I was using, but this is what the issue has been.

I built the app offsite and when I launched it on my production server, I set everything up with `Postgres` settings and ran with it. If anybody has any info on what the caused issue could have been, I would love to hear it!

Comment: In your development environment (or the DigitalOcean box itself if you tunnel in and firewall off public access on 80 and 443) set `DEBUG=True` in your settings and you'll see details of the 500 error. If you can't debug it yourself, post the important portion (usually the main error message) here.

Comment: 500 error comes back because there is an error in your code that is being executed. It gets added to a database because a bit of the code that is failing is after save.

Comment: So I tried setting `Debug=True` but it doesn't report anything, all I see is `Server Error(500)`. And interesting, @marxin... It worked fine when I was hosting it on another server, and flawlessly as well in my development environment

Comment: *So I tried setting Debug=True but it doesn't report anything,* : the issue comes from your server configuration then

Comment: Check the nginx logs at `/var/log/nginx/*error.log` and report back with what you find.

Comment: So the error logs are showing nothing relating to this. My suspicions are that it has something to do with the fact that this app was built using MySQL and when I launched it, I changed quickly over to postgresql... I am converting back now to see if that is part of the issue